# How to use single quote with strcat?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to add a single quote in my string that is being concatenated using `strcat`. How do I get this to work?

I want a string: `abc'`, but I could not do the following

```
strcat('abc'')
```

Comment: In general there is nothing wrong with following the Q&A style, but when I google your exact question title the first returned result already presents the answer. The same holds for related queries. Hence consider whether it really adds value to post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `'` in the string, you need to use two single quotes in your expression.

The modified expression is:

```
 strcat('abc''')
```